# Sending Multicast UDP by GCDAsyncUdpSocket fails, no activity in Wireshark

Tags: ios, sockets, udp, multicast, gcdasyncsocket

It works okay for any known IP like this:

```
[udpSocket sendData:datatosend toHost:@"192.168.1.113" port:port withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

But when i'm trying to use broadband multicast, nothing logged and nothing goes on

```
[udpSocket sendData:datatosend toHost:@"192.168.1.255" port:port withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

receiving works okay, i also tried 255.255.255.255 - the same. 
it doesn't give any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
[udpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:nil];
```