# Wireshark: Filter by Multicast in GUI

Tags: filtering, multicast, wireshark

Using the Wireshark "Filter" field in the Wireshark GUI, I would like to filter capture results so that only multicast packets are shown.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728285/sending-multicast-udp-by-gcdasyncudpsocket-fails-no-activity-in-wireshark) but that doesn't work for the GUI filter field. [This Wireshark page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) shows how to filter out multicast, but not how to filter everything *but* multicast.

Does anyone know of a simple statement that will do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just use this `(eth.dst[0] & 1)` . Multicast traffic is recognized by the least significant bit of the most significant byte of the MAC address. If 1, multicast, if 0, not.

Comment: That produces the Wireshark error `"multicast" was unexpected in this context`. Any ideas? I wonder if there is simply a syntax issue. `ip==multicast` didn't produce an error, but it doesn't show any resuts either (and there are many many multicast packets that should be showing).

Comment: Did you try `ip==multicast and ether==multicast`?

Comment: As mentioned above, `ip==multicast` didn't produce any results. `ether==multicast` produces the Wireshark error `Neither "ether" nor "multicast" are field or protocol names.`

Comment: Edited my answer with a more direct solution

Comment: This also displays broadcast, see mojjj's answer.

Comment: That is true, but broadcast is a type of multicast traffic. So this still answers the original question. @mojjj's answer is still beneficial because it does provide a way to explicitly exclude broadcast.

Comment: Sorry my bad, would like to remove the downvote but can't

Answer (score 22):

```
(eth.dst[0]&1)
```

will filter both multicast and broadcast. So, from this exclude broadcast. It will be like

```
(eth.dst[0]&1) && !eth.dst==ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: What worked for me was `eth.dst[0]&1 && eth.dst!=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

Answer (score 4):

I came across this solution by a process of trial and error.

Since a multicast address begins "1110" (128+64+32+0 = 224), a packet sent to a an IP address beginning 1110 is destined for a multicast address.  Therefor, a packet matching the mask 224.0.0.0/4 is destined for a multicast address.

This display filter should therefor filter packets to multicast addresses only:

```
ip.dst==224.0.0.0/4
```

Comment: I think this must be the solution for the network packets with IP layer. Using MAC address information for broadcast is more general solution.

Comment: Note that this filter display **IPv4** multicast only, hiding **IPv6**.

Answer (score 4):

With Wireshark (2.2.6 version for Linux) is possible to choose the filter "**eth.ig == 1**"

It refer to "IG bit" that is present in the Ethernet Frame.

The IG bit distinguishes whether the MAC address is an individual or group (hence IG) address. In other words, an IG bit of 0 indicates that this is a unicast MAC address, an IG bit of 1 indicates a multicast or broadcast address.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried just using `multicast` as your filter? Because if `not multicast` filters out all multicast packets and lets through everything else as the page you linked seems to state, then that's only logical.

Comment: I did try that but Wireshark gives the error `"multicast" is neither a field nor a protocol name`.

Comment: Oh, looks like that's because it's actually a capture filter rather than a display filter. Sorry for not noticing before.